# automatic and recurring persistence JPA + Hibernate + Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Personal asking here because I am catching and not found anywhere .. hehe .
I'm doing a persistence adding the date manually . When the user mark that eh recurring movement that will automatically persist in 30 days without time to finish . I'm using spring 3 + jpa + hibernate and EntityManager javax.persist . Already use one EntityListener class with an annotated class with @pospersist

I need a lot of help ..

obs . using MySql

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: post your code and let us know where do you need help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Comment: And, you should be using spring-data by now. it'll fix everything for you. Spring-data-rest is even more useful, especially when used with spring-boot.